# Reading a specific overview layer from GeoTIFF file using GDAL / Python

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I know how to create the overviews to a specific geoTIFF file using GDAL ( i have tested it in QGIS), but I cannot find any good information on how to read these overviews individually in Python.

```
gdal.SetConfigOption('HFA_USE_RRD', 'YES')
outData = gdal.Open("test2.tiff",gdal.GA_Update)
outData.BuildOverviews(overviewlist=[2,4,8])
```

i would expect the answer to be something like:

```
array = outData.GetOverviews(overviewlist = 2)
```

Comment: How about [`outdata.GetOverview(2)`](http://www.gdal.org/classGDALRasterBand.html#a2ab58ccaef2a64ad938cd69973c6ace1)?

Comment: It seems like i dont have that function. i have just installed the OSgeo4w64, is this function not available? 


    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'GetOverview'
    >>>

Comment: I checked my gdal version. it says: 1.11.3

Answer (score 2):

The reason to my problem was that I was not calling the function from the right class. `GetOverview` is called from the class `Band`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the python gdal code to extract overview from Sentinel 2 JP2 format with overview level 2 (0-index).

```
import gdal
jp2 = "T32UMD_20190727T104029_TCI_10m.jp2"

dataset = gdal.Open(jp2)

band1 = dataset.GetRasterBand(1);
overview1 = band1.GetOverview(2);

band2 = dataset.GetRasterBand(2);
overview2 = band2.GetOverview(2);    

band3 = dataset.GetRasterBand(3);
overview3 = band3.GetOverview(2);

arr1 = overview1.ReadAsArray()
arr2 = overview2.ReadAsArray()
arr3 = overview3.ReadAsArray()

[cols, rows] = arr1.shape

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
outdata = driver.Create("test_overview.tiff", rows, cols, 3, gdal.GDT_Byte)

outdata.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(arr1)
outdata.GetRasterBand(2).WriteArray(arr2)
outdata.GetRasterBand(3).WriteArray(arr3)

outdata.FlushCache() ##saves to disk!!
outdata = None
band=None
ds=None
```